# Combine array and variable php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, insert

I have created an empty array above my foreach loop. I want to add my variable $filedir to my array until the foreach loop finish.

This is my code:

```
$fileopslag = array();
foreach($searchdoc as $searchdocument){
$filedir = 'd:\Documentatie/'.$searchdocument->pagename; 
$fileopslag = $filedir; 
}
```

When I do this, it adds the variable one time to my array.

When I show my output with var_dump, I see this:

"string(23) "d:\Documentatie/16.html", one string, but not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not storing data into array rather directly updating by a string in each iterration in the loop.
do

```
$fileopslag[] = $filedir;
```